# How to find $\lim_{x\to\infty} (-x^3-3x+2)?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I calculate the following limit$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (-x^3-3x+2)?$$

I'm clueless!

Comment: Tried factorizing it?

Comment: If $p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0$ then $p(x)\sim a_nx^n$ when $x\to\infty$

Comment: @BabakS. I didn't know the result. I want more clarification.

Comment: @SritiMallick: The other terms get negligible when $x\to infinity$

Comment: Why do other terms get negligible? You mean for $\epsilon>0~\exists~r\in\mathbb R$ such that $|p(x)-a_nx^n|<\epsilon$ for $x>r?$

Comment: Notice in this case, $-(x^3-3x)$, $x^3$ travels faster than $3x$ to infinity when the x tends to infinity! Refer to this: http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/limits-infinity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim: $\lim_{x\to \infty} (-x^3-3x+2)=-\infty$.

Proof by definition:
If $x$ is sufficiently large (e.g. $x>10$) then $x^3>6x-4$ and in particular $x^3/2>x$. So using these two inequalities we have 
$$
-x^{3}-3x+2 = -\frac{x^3}{2} - (\frac{x^3-6x+4}{2})< -x.
$$ 
Thus for every $N>0$ if $x>\max(N,10)$, it follows that $-x^3-3x+2<-N$, qed.

Answer (score 1):

In a polynomial $\lim_{x \to \infty}(a_nx^n+...+a_0)=a_nx^n$

When x tends to $\infty$, $-x^3$ approaches to $-\infty$ and same is with $-3x$, as 2 is negligible when compared to $\infty$, it can be neglected. Hence, the limit evaluates to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (-x^3-3x+2)$$

if $x\to\infty, -x^3-3x+2\equiv  -x^3$

so we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (-x^3-3x+2)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} (-x^3)$$
$$=-\infty$$